# Please help me with my Minecraft

Tags: minecraft

I have bought Minecraft and downloaded it from the official site.
It said that once it is downloaded, it will operate immediately, but instead, I have a box that says Minecraft.jar.
When I click on it, it says "open with Open JDK Java6 runtime".
I am not sure what to do next...Please help me.
Also, I am very bad at IT, so please explain things very simply and basicly.

Thank you! (　^▽^)ノ

Comment: I tried opening it on JDK java7 runtime, but this happens:

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft downloaded from official site needs Oracle JRE to run properly. Running it with OpenJDK is a bit hassle you probably want to avoid. Install the snap version of Minecraft instead. Pres **ctrl+alt+t** to open **Terminal**. In there, type-

> sudo snap install mc-installer

Press **Enter**. It'll ask for your password, enter it and again press **Enter** (password will remain completely invisible during typing, this is normal). Give it some times to finish downloading & installing Minecraft. After installation, search for Minecraft in your program menu and run it.